# Simperium is not syncing data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, simperium

I am developing iOS application using Simperium. When I login simperium then it works properly means it syncing data properly. And once user login then he will remain logged in untill he will not logout. So if app goes in background then he will remain logged in. Well, problem is that when application goes in background or if not active for some duration like for 3-4 hours and when app comes in foreground then simperium data is not synced properly as per expected and if I logout and login again then data synced properly. So as I think it because of Something session like problem means Simperium has fixed session time after that it expired, is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Simperium relies on a WebSocket connection to communicate changes back and forth the backend.

As long as the user is effectively logged in, and the Authentication Token is still valid, the library is expected to automatically deal with reconnections / timeouts, and that includes FG / BG switches.

Few questions for you:

- Which authentication method are you using? Token based or UI?
- Have you wired "backgroundFetchWithCompletion" ?
- If you kill the app, and relaunch, does Sync'ing remain stuck?
- Which iOS version are you using? did you repro on the device or Simulator?
- Can you please confirm if you're using the latest Simperium version?

Please, by all means, feel free to open an issue on the main repository (https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios). Make sure to include verbose logs, we'd be happy to take a look.

Thanks!